# Are the Dominating Families Of Functions (Domsets) Uncountable?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, set-theory

#### Preface :

For $f, g: \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$, we write $f \leqslant^* g$ for
$$
\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant m} f(n) \leqslant g(n) .
$$
Let us call a set $\mathcal{D}$ a **domset** if

(i) all the elements of $\mathcal{D}$ are functions $\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$; and

(ii) for every $f: \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$, there exists $g \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $f \leqslant^* g$.

#### Question :

Are **all** domsets uncountable?

Now surely, the **specific** domset containing **all** functions $\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$ is uncountable since the symmetric group $\sum_{\mathbb{Z\geqslant 0}}$ is uncountable and is a subset of the set of all functions $\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$. But I'm unsure if all domsets are uncountable.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @bof That should be an answer. (Meanwhile, to the OP: you may be interested in the general topic of **cardinal characteristics of the continuum**. Your question is about one of these, usually denoted "$\mathfrak{d}$.")

Comment: Thank you @NoahSchweber for your comment and direction on cardinal characteristics of the continuum. Umm as for [@]bof, I cannot see his comment. Maybe he deleted it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to delete my comment because it contained a typo and the time limit had expired for editing it. I could try to repost it, but since Noah Schweber is an expert on set theory, he can post a much better answer than I could.

Comment: The point of my deleted comment was that a countable set can't be a "domset" because, given a countable set of functions, a straightforward "diagonalization" will get you a function which dominates them all.

Comment: @bof Indeed  I also thought about it. Here is my train of thought. Find a sequence $g_{0}, g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots \in \mathcal{D}$ in which every element of $\mathcal{D}$ appears.

Define $f: \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$ by setting $f(n)=\max \left\{g_{0}(n), g_{1}(n), \ldots, g_{n}(n)\right\}+1$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$.  This shows $\forall g \in \mathcal{D} \sim \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0} \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant m} f(n) \leqslant g(n)$. But isn't that seriously wrong? Here $f$ cannot be the $max$ of an infinite seq.

Comment: Indeed, would be massively grateful if the great expert @NoahSchweber can officially post an answer. I would love to see his train of thought!

Comment: That is exactly the construction I suggested in my deleted comment. Why do you consider it "seriously wrong"?

Comment: When $n$ gets infinitely large then $max{}$ ceases to be well defined isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what the word salad "when $n$ gets infinitely large" is supposed to mean, but no such thing comes up in the (correct) construction you described. No matter how large it is, the natural number $n$ is still finite, and the maximum of the $n+1$ numbers $g_0(n),\dots,g_n(n)$ is well defined.